# ListView with AsyncTask not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to show images on a list view. In a cell I'm showing 4 images at a time. When I'm not using the AsynkTask, it working but it's not smooth scrolling. So I'm trying to use Asynktasks. But in my implementation, it shows nothing.

**Without AsyncTask**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private File[] data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, File[] files) {
        activity = a;
        data=files;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length / 4 + 1;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.icon2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.icon3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            holder.icon4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            holder.position = position;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(position >= 0){

                            if(data.length > position * 4){
                                holder.icon1.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[position * 4]));
                            }
                            if(data.length > position * 4 + 1){
                                holder.icon2.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[position * 4 + 1]));
                            }
                            if(data.length > position * 4 + 2){
                                holder.icon3.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[position * 4 + 2]));
                            }
                            if(data.length > position * 4 + 3){
                                holder.icon4.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[position * 4 + 3]));
                            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**With AsyncTask**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private File[] data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, File[] files) {
        activity = a;
        data=files;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length / 4 + 1;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.icon2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.icon3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            holder.icon4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            holder.position = position;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(position >= 0){
            new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(ViewHolder... v) {
                    v[0].icon1.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[v[0].position * 4]));
                    v[0].icon2.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[v[0].position * 4 + 1]));
                    v[0].icon3.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[v[0].position * 4 + 2]));
                    v[0].icon4.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(data[v[0].position * 4 + 3]));
                    LazyAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute(holder);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I recommend you to use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader for image downloading, if it is possible of course. This library will take care about image loading, caching and placing to your view. And it works brilliant with listviews.

Comment: You can simply use `Universal-ImageLoader` class.

Comment: This is not actually downloading images. In this, only showing the images on `Picture` folder

Comment: Your updating the UI from the other thread..which will throw exception..

Comment: Problem for this issue is because of the getview is calling every scrooling time and you are using the Asynctask in your getview so it will call at every scrolling so only you are not getting the smooth scrolling....

Comment: I just tried to follow this. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this type of list easily... You will use like this...
Here also am using the asynctask but here i download and store that image in cache memory So it give the smooth scrolling You  will try like this....

public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private String[] mImagePaths;
private Activity mActivity;
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
public static LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> sGalleryBitmap;
public static int sCheckValue = 0;
public static int sCheckingFlags[] = null;

public GalleryAdapter(Activity a, String[] mGalleryString) {
    super();
    this.mActivity = a;
    this.mImagePaths = mGalleryString;
    this.mContext = (Context) mActivity.getBaseContext();
     final int cacheSize = 20*1024*1024;
    sGalleryBitmap = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(cacheSize){          
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(Integer key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }
    };
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    GalleryAdapter.sCheckingFlags = null;
    GalleryAdapter.sCheckingFlags = new int[mImagePaths.length];
    sCheckValue = 0;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mImagePaths.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    convertView = null;
    int n = 1;
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_support, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imgDisplay = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.galleryimage);
    if (ViewerActivity.sResource == position) {
        holder.imgDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redback);
        n = 0;
    }
    holder.bar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bar);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    if (getBitmapFromMemCacheGallery(position)== null) {
        load o1 = new load(position, holder.imgDisplay, holder.bar);
        o1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                mImagePaths[position]);
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.imgDisplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redback);
        }

    } else {
        if (GalleryAdapter.sCheckingFlags[position] == 1) {
            holder.imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromMemCacheGallery(position));
        } else {
            holder.imgDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.galleryalart);
        }
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(140, 140));
    } else {
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(140, 140));
    }
    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgDisplay;
    ProgressBar bar;
}

private class load extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView imageView;
    ProgressBar bar;
    int position;

    public load(int position, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar bar) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.position = position;
        this.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];

        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            URLConnection connection;
            connection = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);//ViewerActivity.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(in, 140,140);
            if(mIcon!=null)
            {
                addBitmapToMemoryCacheGallery(position, mIcon);
            }               
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mIcon = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,
                    140));
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
            GalleryAdapter.sCheckingFlags[position] = 1;                
        } else {
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.galleryalart);
            GalleryAdapter.sCheckingFlags[position] = 0;
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Drawable myDrawable = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.galleryalart);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
            addBitmapToMemoryCacheGallery(position, bitmap);
        }
    }

}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void addBitmapToMemoryCacheGallery(Integer position, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCacheGallery(position) == null) {           
        sGalleryBitmap.put(position, bitmap);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCacheGallery(Integer imageKey) {
    return sGalleryBitmap.get(imageKey);
}

}
```